# AutoFixture with Entity Framework - mapping int to enum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, enums, autofixture

I would like to use AutoFixture (3.30.8) against my Entity Framework (6.1.3) data model. I have implemented the AutoFixture.AutoEF (0.3.5) package to help fix up the entities and avoid the circular references generated by the relationships.

However, my tables have several int columns which are represented by enums in code and I would like to be able to set the int values based on the enum values and have a proxy class for each of the enum values.

Here is a much simplified example of my schema:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public partial class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Children = new HashSet<Child>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public partial class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my enums:

```
public enum Status
{
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2
}

public enum Type
{
    Up = 1,
    Down = 2,
    Left = 3,
    Right = 4
}
```

And here is how I am creating the proxies:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();

fixture.Customize(new EntityCustomization(new DbContextEntityTypesProvider(typeof(MyContext))));

var parents = fixture.CreateMany<Parent>();
```

This works in that I have a collection of 3 `Parent` classes each with 3 `Child` classes and the Id properties nicely match up. However, as expected, the `Status` and `Type` properties are random ints as generated by AutoFixture.

What I would like to have is 2 `Parent` classes, one with `Status` of `1` and one with `Status` of `2` and for each of those to have 4 `Child` classes, each one of those to have `Type` of `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.

Is this possible automatically using AutoFixture?

**EDIT:** To make it clearer what I am asking:

How can I automatically map an int property on my class to an enum so that I get one proxy class for each value of the mapped enum.

This will also need to work where a class has 2 or more mapped enums.

e.g. If `Child` has `Type` and `Status` properties, I would expect 8 `Children` per `Parent`:

```
Status = 1, Type = 1
Status = 1, Type = 2
Status = 1, Type = 3
Status = 1, Type = 4
Status = 2, Type = 1
Status = 2, Type = 2
Status = 2, Type = 3
Status = 2, Type = 4
```

And to extrapolate further, if `Parent` also had both `Status` and `Type` I would expect 8 `Parent` proxy classes, each with 8 `Child` proxy classes.

**EDIT 2:** Here is a sample of how my manually coded substitutes generator looks, if I've put both enums on both classes. By using AutoFixture I can automate everything except for the looping to generate every permutation of the Enums. *That* is what I am asking how to do.

```
public class Substitutes
{
    private int parentIdSeed;

    private int childIdSeed;

    public Substitutes()
    {
        this.parentIdSeed = 0;

        this.childIdSeed = 0;

        this.Parents = new List<Parent>();

        this.Children = new List<Child>();

        this.GenerateParents();
    }

    private void GenerateParents()
    {
        foreach (Type type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type)))
        {
            foreach (Status status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)))
            {
                this.parentIdSeed++;

                var parent = new Parent { Id = this.parentIdSeed, Name = "Parent " + this.parentIdSeed, Status = (int)status, Type = (int)type };

                this.GenerateChildren(parent);

                this.Parents.Add(parent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateChildren(Parent parent)
    {
        foreach (Type type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type)))
        {
            foreach (Status status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)))
            {
                this.childIdSeed++;

                var child = new Child { Id = this.childIdSeed, Name = "Child " + this.childIdSeed, Status = (int)status, Type = (int)type, Parent = parent, ParentId = parent.Id };

                parent.Children.Add(child);

                this.Children.Add(child);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible:

```
var parents = fixture.CreateMany<Parent>(2).ToList();

parents[1].Status = 1;
parents[1].Children = fixture.CreateMany<Child>(4).ToList();
parents[1].Children.ElementAt(1).Type = 1;
parents[1].Children.ElementAt(2).Type = 2;
parents[1].Children.ElementAt(3).Type = 3;
parents[1].Children.ElementAt(4).Type = 4;

parents[2].Status = 2;
parents[2].Children = fixture.CreateMany<Child>(4).ToList();
parents[2].Children.ElementAt(1).Type = 1;
parents[2].Children.ElementAt(2).Type = 2;
parents[2].Children.ElementAt(3).Type = 3;
parents[2].Children.ElementAt(4).Type = 4;
```

Comment: I provided a very simplified version of my schema. My actual schema is across a dozen tables, some with multiple enums and some of the enums run to dozens of values. Your solution doesn't scale very well! I am looking for an automated way of doing this via AutoFixture

Comment: I am basically already doing my substitutes this way, but fully manually coded for every property.

Comment: How do you propose to automate something that has a very specific requirements (2 of those, 4 of those, etc.)?

Comment: by the number of items in the enum. As I said, I already do this manually by a foreach on the enum values

Comment: What if the requested type has more than one property corresponding to different enums, with a different number of values? How many should be created then?

Comment: See my edit, I explained that - every permutation should be covered

Comment: @Shevek Which purpose would that serve?

Comment: To be able to write unit tests against all the permutations

Comment: If a class has a `byte` property, would you also want all 256 possible values? How about an `int` property? All 4,294,967,296 possible values? How about a type with both a `byte` and an `int` property? All 1,099,511,627,520 permutations?

Comment: Seriously? Why are you questioning my question so much? I have several requirements which need particular actions to happen depending on the type and current status of a record. Therefore I need a test substitute for each of those permutations. Its as simple as that.

Comment: Seriously. In C#, an `enum` is only syntactic sugar that assigns a label to a number. At run-time, it *is* a number, and conceptually, it *is* a number. If you think it's ridiculous to generate values for all integers, then why is it sensible to generate all values for an `enum`?

Comment: I am fully aware of what an enum is/isn't. How many times do I have to say the same thing? I am creating test substitutes to cover all of the business rules that I have to test against. The rules around other int properties such as Ids are simple, so I don't need every possible eventuality, just the boundaries (i.e. if the rule is greater than or equal to x then I need one for x, one for x -1 and one for x + 1). For some of my ints which are represented in code by enums, I need to write tests that cover all permutations, therefore I need a substitute for each of those possibilities. Simple!